# How to use WMPLib in C#

Tags: c#, wmplib

I'm trying to import WMPLib but Visual Studio but it's giving message
`Type or Namespace name 'WMPLib' could not be found`.
I also tried using System.Windows.Media but again for Media it's giving same message.
I tried adding in toolbox Windows Media Player from

```
Choose Tool Box Items->Com Components->Windows Media Player
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 9):

*To create the Windows Media Player control programmatically, you must first add a reference to wmp.dll, which is found in the \Windows\system32 folder. Adding this reference creates WMPLib.dll in your project folder, and a reference to WMPLib appears in Solution Explorer.*

The following Link will help you.

[Creating the Windows Media Player Control Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. Still same message.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message, coz the above solution worked for us.

Comment: I'm developing my project in Visual studio 2012. When I use code `using WMPLib;` it shows following error `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'WMPLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\c#.net\new_project\FirstWinService\FirstWinService\SchedulerService.cs 10 7 FirstWinService
`

Comment: You also need to add `using WMPLib;` at the top of your file.